# What is the sObject for storing Change sets in Salesforce?

Tags: deployment, change-set

Working on Package related to deployment in salesforce, wanted to understand where changeset is stored at the backend in salesforce.

Please help me understand this, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

As far as the Metadata API is concerned, they are just a normal [Package](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_package.htm). You can retrieve and update them as you would a normal Package, with special limitations (e.g. you can't update a Change Set once it's uploaded).

Comment: @sfdx basically need is to create a new changeset without using salesforce UI, is there any way to do that?

Comment: @SakshiSehdev No can do, as far as I can tell. You must create the initial shell in the UI, and then you can retrieve and work with it. This isn't likely to change in the future, as new projects should use Unlocked Packages for this purpose.

Comment: @SakshiSehdev For historical context, Change Sets predate the metadata API, so they were backfilled in to the API when it came out (or sometime later). As a result, they're kind of just a vestigial leftover from classic in-house development. I'd recommend Unlocked Packages as the way forward.

Comment: @sfdx is that means we do not have anything for now for this in salesforce?

Comment: @SakshiSehdev You cannot create a Change Set by API, only update it.